# LLC working above resonance

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, resonance

I am designing LLC Half-Bridge converter:

Pout = 500W, Out = 12V, Vin = 390V, Fr = 80kHz, Lr = 30 uH, Cr = 120nF, Lp = 190uH

The converter is working always above resonant frequency.  The oscillographs you see are measured in 200W Pout.  As you can see the green channel is Lr current, red channel is switching node and yellow channel is capacitor voltage.

First question: what could be the reason for low efficiency 93.7% (transistor heated to 95°C and transformer to 80°C, measured at max power)?

Second question: why capacitor voltage is not dropping to zero? Even when I make simulations in LTspice with the resonant frequency, the voltage looks like in the shown picture from LTspice.

I understand that the RMS voltage across the capacitor is regulated by the feedback and is satisfying the formula \$V_\textrm{cap} = V_\textrm{out} N = (12\,V) (16) = 192\,V\$ where N is turns ratio.

Thing that I thought about: resonant frequency is going high probably because Lr value is decreasing with current.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please label the nets in your LTSpice simulation; we have no idea what `n008` etc. are. What transistor are you using? Surely not the STP8NM60 (0.9Ω Rds(on)) on the sim.  What inductor and transformer, or winding diagram if custom? What does the layout look like?

Comment: N008 is SW node 
N010 is Voltage across capacitor 
blue waveform is resonant current thru L1.

The transistors I have used are IPP65R190CFDXKSA1.